# Is it normal that static member values are retained when an application is destroyed?

Tags: java, android, static-members

Unexpectedly I realized that my static class members are retained after application is finish
(after onDestroy() is called).
Static members initializations are ignored in next application instantiation.
Is it normal or it is only a bug in emulator?
I can't find anything about it in documentation. Do they specify anything connected to this behavior?

Additional comments:
When I have two fields in activity, static and non static like this:

```
static String s1 = new String("s1");
String s2 = new String("s2");
```

...and destroy and start application again, the first initializer is not executed and the second one is executed. Where is the sense? For me it violates language rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an application starts, its own vm is started and the main activity is started. When that activity is left (eg. back button pressed or you call finish()) onDestroy() is executed.

While that technically ends your application your application process and vm is still running. That includes running threads.

So all static members remain intact. The system can kill the vm once it requires more memory at any time while it is not showing.

Comment: Ok, so I see that static member initialization is useless and everything that can change must be assigned at start in code.

Comment: @ardabro Static attributes are not useless, but should be used for the specific purpose for which they are intended. They are often used in Java applications to store constants (often forced to be immutable using the `final` keyword), but they are also useful in other scenarios, such as where the values are common and consistent across instances of the class.

Comment: Definitely not useless--it's just that the lifecycle of an Android app differs from a typical Java app where startup/shutdown are controlled more explicitly.

Comment: I din't write that static attributes are useless. Useless is static initialization of members that can change during application.

Answer (score 2):

`onDestroy` doesn't mean the application's processes are being killed, or that the class itself destroyed/unloaded, it's destroying an activity *instance*.

Comment: So what is the answer? Aplpications are newer killed? Live forever?

Comment: The answer, implied, is that your assumption regarding onDestroy is incorrect, and you're asking the wrong question. Are you actually asking about when are apps completely removed (like a force stop)?

Comment: BTW: Considering that initializers of non static members of the Activity are executed again when application is restarted we know for sure that new Activity class instance is constructed - so your answer is not proper. Application is _not_ frozen. It preserves only static members.

Comment: @ardabro I never said anything about being "frozen"--we're discussing class loading, which is when static members are initialized, and has nothing to do with instance property initialization--precisely what the answer you accepted also states. And you were, in fact, asking the wrong question--you wanted to know when an application is re-loaded, triggering a class-reload, which is when static initializers are run; also what I said.

Comment: I think @ardabro you're confusing what a static attribute is, and the lifecycle of a Java class in the context of an Android application.  I'm not an Android developer, but from what Dave Newton is saying, it would appear that when you close the application, onDestroy() is called, and the instance is destroyed. When you restart the application, a new instance is created. The static elements of the class have not been unloaded, because the same VM is used when you restart the application.